# How can I manage lots of android Imageviews?

Tags: android, imageview

I have 20 ImageViews in my Activity. I need one method to manage them easily.

My code is like this right now:

```
Imageview img1 = (Imageview) findviewbyid(R.id.imageview1);
img1.setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.image1);

Imageview img2 = (Imageview) findviewbyid(R.id.imageview2);
img2.setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.image2);

Imageview img3 = (Imageview) findviewbyid(R.id.imageview3);
img3.setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.image3);
.
.
.
```

but I need an easier way!

Comment: So if calling `setBackgroundResource()` which is one common method that has been there since API level 1 not qualifies as "easy" then what does? How about you start by explaining what exactly is wrong with your code in its current state...

Comment: why dont you use grid or list

Comment: can i use a string as an imageview's name?

Comment: can u give an example of grid or list?

Comment: If you're starting out with Android I highly recommend you this free video course from Google: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853

Comment: Make `int` image array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of ids with all your resources:

```
int[] myIds = {R.id.imageview1, R.id.imageview2, R.id.imageview3, ...};
int[] myDrawables = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, ...};
```

Then iterate through it using a for loop, while, a `map` function (I know this is Java 6...).

```
for (int i = 0; i< myIds.length; i++) {
     Imageview img = (Imageview) findviewbyid(myIds[i]);
     img.setbackgroundresource(myDrawables[i]);
}
```

Although it would be better to use a GridView / ListView with an Adapter for that

Answer (score 0):

It seems all your resources are not dynamically defined. Why don't you just set them in your xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image1"/>
```